# Quartz - Get data out of job post-execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, persistence, quartz-scheduler

Everyone talks about PersistJobDataAfterExecution, but that doesn't seem to work unless you execute the job again, which I have no interest in doing. Why would I execute a job twice when it works fine the first time. Furthermore, if it's persisted, then where? JobDetail doesn't exist post execution.

I store data in the JobDataMap, and use that in order to get progress of the job **while it's running** (via ajax web calls). And when the job **finishes execution**, it **deletes** it's own trigger and therefore the scheduler no longer has JobDetail, and therefore no JobDataMap.

Normally I would store the data in the Application cache, but I can't, because this data is specific to a user session. 
ASP.net HttpContext is unavailable from a Quartz thread.

How can I get data out of a executed (past tense) Quartz Job, when the thread is totally independent, and Pausing the job, and Interrupting the job, both result in the same outcome as letting it complete execute(IContext) whereby it destroys itself?

Do I really have to run an infinite sleep loop, in order to externally attain data from it, and then hard-kill it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using HttpRuntime.Cache, since it's thread-safe. 
It's the easiest solution, as opposed to the underwhelming alternatives: 
  calling the job twice(PersistJobDataAfterExecution), using sleep loops(hackish), changing quartz to use ADO(bleh), posting to SynchronizationContext(unstable), or writing to disk(super bleh).